# Looking for inheritance solutions

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

This is my scenario in Java:

```
interface I{}
class A implements I{}
class B extends A{}
```

So, now which class needs to implement the interface's I methods? What if A and B classes share implementation?
Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`class A` has to provide all implementations since it's not `abstract`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) for more details.

`class` B can override any/all of those methods.

If you make `A` abstract (as a class), then it can provide `abstract` methods for those methods in the interface (essentially just declaring them as `abstract`) and `B` would provide the only implementation.

Answer (score 1):

1) Class A has to implement the Interface I's method.

2) Class B can however, override these definitions if required.

3) Class A should be declared abstract if it is not implementing, in which case, Class B should implement these.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to implement the I interface in the A class. Optionally you can override that implementation in the B class, but if you don't do it both classes will behave in the same way (using A implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Stating `implements` you promise that class will implement some interface. Stating `extends` you allow yourself to reuse implementation from base class. `extends` implies `implements`.

So in your case you promised that `A` will implement `I`. Next you promised that `B` will also implement `I` but will use `A`'s implementation as a base.

So, your pattern supposing that `B` with share some implementation with `A` concerning `A` as a source. It is ok if this is what you want.

You can also:

1) state `class B implements I` in this case `B` will be at it's own.

2) hold majority of implementation in some third class, called for instance `Base`, like follows

```
interface I {}
class Base implements I {}
class A extends Base{}
class B extends Base{}
```

this way `A` and `B` will be of equal rights.

3) You can hold implementation in any arbitrary class and use aggregation and decorate it:

```
interface I {
   String method1(String a);
   String method2(String a);
}
class ImplementationHolder1 // does not implement I!
{ 
   String method1impl(String a) {};
}
class ImplementationHolder2 // does not implement I!
{ 
   String method2impl(String a) {};
}

class A implements I {
     ImplementationHolder1 h1;
     ImplementationHolder2 h2;
     String method1(String a) {
         return h1.method1impl();
     };
     String method2(String a) {
         return h2.method2impl();
     };
}
```

Remember, that you should make class `abstract` if it implement interface not fully.

Also you can override any base class implementation in descendant class if it is not matching your needs.